# ReactJS onChange, if nested hash/json

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, hash, coffeescript

I only learning ReactJS, and I'm stuck on simple logic (I really bad in JS). I have a form, what contain name, email and message.

```
@ContactUsNew = React.createClass
  getInitialState: ->
    message: @props.message
  getDefaultProps: ->
    message: { name: '', email: '', message: ''}
  handleChange: (event) ->
    name = event.target.name
    console.log @setState message: { "#{ name }": event.target.value }
```

And I don't know how to work this line `@setState message: "#{ name }": event.target.value` to work, since I have build this hash `message: { name: '', email: '', message: '' }`.

What I'm trying to archive is to update with `@setState` individual component of hash/json.

If I do like this `@setState message: { "#{ name }": event.taget.value }` the result will be `message: { email: foo@bar.com }` (if email was typed in last).

I just don't know how to update each element of hash/json sepperatly.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is written in coffeescript by the way.

You just need to make the changes to the `message` object, and `setState` the entire thing.. Ideally you will create a copy, something like this using [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

```
copy = Object.assign {}, @state.message, { "#{ name }": event.target.value }
@setState message: copy
```

Comment: Yeah, I know it's coffee, I still can write simple things in js, jQuery, and coffee, but want to make my skills better with js. Didn't test what you propose, but will I receive uncontrollable warning? (because I've tried to substitute value and received `You cannot switch from controllable to uncontrollable ` error.